# How can I rotate a shape and have it move in the same direction that it is facing in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, rotation

I am rotating a shape in Java using g2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationDegrees), x, y) where the x and the y are the axis that I want the shape to be rotating along. When I try to move the shape with a key listener, the shape still moves up, down, left, and right instead of moving according to the angle that it is facing. Is there any way that I can rotate a shape and have it move in the same direction that it is facing?
[image: What I want the code to do]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little bit of trigonometry before you change your `x` and `y` values.  Maintain a variable `angle` which stores the total amount that your shape has rotated from its initial position.

Now suppose you've got variables `xChange` and `yChange` that represent the desired change in `x` and `y`, but in the reference frame of the shape, not of the frame.  Then instead of writing `x += xChange;` you'd write

```
x += (xChange * Math.cos(angle) + yChange * Math.sin(angle));
```

and instead of writing `y += yChange;` you'd write

```
y += (yChange * Math.cos(angle) - xChange * Math.sin(angle));
```

This assumes that `angle` is stored in radians, not degrees.  You may also need to experiment with the `+` and `-` signs, depending on whether you're measuring `y` from top to bottom or bottom to top.